# CSS change background on image background mouse hover

Tags: css

In my php page dynamically visualize the thumbnails. To make sure that these are all of the same size I do in this way

```
<a class="zoom" href="...">
<img src="thumb/default.png" width="130" style="background-image:url(thumb/<?php echo $images_jpg;?>);" class="centered" />
</a>
```

CSS

```
img.centered {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}

/* 1 attempt */
a.zoom:hover {
background-image: url(thumb/zoom.jpg);
}

/* 2 attempt */
a.zoom img:hover {
background-image: url(thumb/zoom.jpg);
}
```

I would like to display a different image on event: hover, but this does not work. How could I do that? thanks

Comment: try setting display: block to the img

Comment: is it like if you hover on image, u shud see the image present in the background????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do it like this.

### HTML:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image:url(http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/head.jpg);">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay:hover {
    background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-lJWLTzn8Zgw/T_D4aeKvD9I/AAAAAAAACnM/SnupcVnAsNk/s1600/Random-wallpapers-random-5549791-1280-800.jpg);
}
```

So here we have the image you are getting via `PHP` on top as a `div`. And inside we have the overlay, the image you want when a user is hovering. So we set that to 100% width and height so it takes up all of the parent div and set the hover.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/3nnBM/)

Answer (score 1):

In your example the `<img>` always lays over the `<a>` background-image.
To avoid that, you could hide the image on hover. But that is kinda ugly ;)

```
a.zoom:hover {
    background-image: url(thumb/zoom.jpg);
}

a.zoom:hover img
{
   opacitiy: 0;
}
```

Comment: This seemed like a good solution, but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: I can only guess what your problem is. But i think your problem is, that you do not only have one, but multiple zoom images, that you want to change on hover. Since the URL for the zoom-pictures are generated automatically, you should go for a javascript solution. Is that correct?

Comment: in part is correct. I visualize the images taking their names from a db. The images are different sizes and to display the same size I use (style: background.url...) generated dynamically. I just want to show an image/overflow (always the same - "zoom the image") on the thumb mouse over

Comment: @PaoloRossi Check my answer out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img class="centered" src="thumb/default.png"/>
```

and jquery

```
$(".centered").attr("src","second.jpg");
```